# How to setup elasticsearch secure connection using HTTPS through REST API

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to query my data indexed by elasticsearch in Lucene engine, but I want this connection to be secure by using SSL:

```
https://x.y.z.w:9200/index_name/_search?&q=field:value
```

And this is my whole code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">
   <head>
    <title>XHR App Test</title>
    <script>
       function send() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            url = 'https://x.y.z.w:9200/index_name/_search?&q=field:value',
            sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) { 
            console.log(e);
            if (e.currentTarget.readyState > 2) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e.currentTarget.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>XHR App Test</h1>

     <button id='sendButton' onclick="send()">Send</button>
     <div id="result"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I also added these configs in `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```
 http.port: 9200
 http.cors.enabled : true
 http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\//
 http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
 http.cors.allow-headers : "X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"
# http.cors.allow-credentials : true
```

But only be able to query by http protocol not https.

How to resolve this?

Comment: You need to setup SSL/TLS using the Shield plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/ssl-tls.html or with XPack: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/ssl-tls.html

Comment: @Val Agreed. Can you move your comment as an answer? Thanks! :)

Comment: @dadoonet Thanks, done... and happy new year ;-)

Comment: free and open source security for elasticsearch https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't support SSL out-of-the-box. The `http.cors` settings are for enabling and setting up the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross-origin resource sharing) mechanism but have nothing to do with SSL.

If you want your ES cluster to serve requests over HTTPS/SSL, you need to setup SSL/TLS either using the [Shield plugin](http://elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/ssl-tls.html) or preferably with [XPack](http://elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/ssl-tls.html) if you're running ES 5.